# Solving Augmented Matrices (3 systems) at once

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given a matrix 
$$
A = \left[\matrix{1 & 2\\2 & 6}\right]
$$

With

$$
\matrix {
b_1 = \left[\matrix{3\\5}\right]; &
b_2 = \left[\matrix{-1\\2}\right]; &
b_3 = \left[\matrix{2\\0}\right]
}
$$
What I'm tasked to do is to 
solve all three systems at the same time by row reducing the augmented matrix $A\ |\ b_1\ \ b_2\ \ b_3$ using Gauss-Jordan elimination. I'm experienced with it, however I'm not familiar with the notation. Would you guys help me understand the notation and set up the problem for Gauss-Jordan elimination? Thanks!

Comment: How would you solve the system if you only had to solve for $Ax = b_1$?

Comment: @dfan I would do x = A^-1b1, and repeat. However, i'm told to do it this way.

Comment: OK, but that's not Gauss-Jordan elimination. I'll write about Gauss-Jordan elimination in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gauss-Jordan elimination works by constantly simplifying your original equations until you end up with something for which the answer is trivial to see. Let's say you were solving $Ax = b_1$:

$$ \left[\matrix{1 & 2\\2 & 6}\right]\left[\matrix{x_1 \\ x_2}\right] = \left[\matrix{3\\5}\right] $$

That's the same as solving the system of equations

\begin{align}
x_1 + 2x_2 &= 3 \\
2x_1 + 6x_2 &= 5
\end{align}

The way you would solve that back in high school is to subtract twice the first equation from the second to get

\begin{align}
x_1 + 2x_2 &= 3 \\
2x_2 &= -1 \\
\end{align}

Then you could divide the last equation by two:

\begin{align}
x_1 + 2x_2 &= 3 \\
x_2 &= -\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{align}

And subtract twice the second equation from the first to get your final answer:

\begin{align}
x_1  &= 4 \\
x_2 &= -\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{align}

Gauss-Jordan elimination is exactly the same thing, only you just manipulate the numbers instead of writing out the $x$s and $+$s and $=$s.

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 2 & 3 \\2 & 6 & 5 \end{array}\right] \rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 2 & 3 \\0 & 2 & -1 \end{array} \right] \rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 2 & 3 \\0 & 1 & -1/2 \end{array} \right] \rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 0 & 4 \\0 & 1 & -1/2 \end{array} \right]
$$
and now you can just read out your answer $\left[\matrix{4 \\ -1/2} \right]$ from the last column. It works for the same reason that manipulating the equations by hand works.

The problem is asking for you to do this for three different $b$s at once. You could either do the whole thing from scratch three times, or you could notice that you're performing the exact same operations each time (since you're just trying to reduce the first two columns to the identity matrix), and do them all at once by making 3 $b$ columns instead of just one.